# Why infrared light waves is visible through camera?

Tags: optics, infrared-radiation

For example We know that some television manufacturers have the limited IR-based remotes which cannot be seen by our eyes directly but while playing when I just put my camera in front of my TV remote I just saw light but I can't see it directly. So why is it visible through camera rather than our eyes directly ?

I just took one image to show what I saw!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Infrared remote flashes blue light in camera](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17455/)

Comment: @JohnRennie - This is a classic case of the duplicate being a better question than the original, particularly with the image!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: your camera CCD is sensitive to infrared light, while your eye is not.

The real question here is: why does your camera render the infrared light as visible light on the screen? The only answer I can hazard on that is that it allows for more visible photographs when they're taken in low (visible) light.

Comment: The color filters in a 3-color CCD camera all are pretty much transparent to near IR, so there always is a separate IR blocking filter in the optical path.  It's not perfect though, and when the camera's looking straight into an emitter (like in the picture above), enough of the IR light gets through.  If you took the same picture with a monochrome CCD camera (e.g., a night-time surveilance camera) which has no IR filter, that LED would appear so bright as to pretty much wash out the rest of the picture.