# What is the visible spectrum to common mobile phone cameras?

Tags: optics, vision, camera

With my iPhone I can see the IR emitter on a tv remote, which could be around 940nm, but I thought cameras generally tried to filter for the human visible spectrum (i.e. sub 700nm). I'm trying an experiment which utilizes any unmodified phone-based camera and I'm curious of the breadth of it's IR visibility. These specs never seem to be published. Anyone have any information on this? Or a way to test like a wavelength-variable IR emitter?

**EDIT:**
I would love to see a graph similar to the one in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/17485/85655) for common phone cameras. Does this exist?

Comment: If I recall correctly, many digital cameras use an infrared floodlight to help with focusing, which would explain why they don't filter out those wavelengths.

Comment: @Asher not many these days.  The ones that did, IIRC, had  a separate focussing channel sans IR filter.

Comment: This is engineering, it does not ask for any physical principle, just for specific data of specific devices.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you're not likely to get any better chart than the one in the link you provided unless you can track down the OEM of the cameras supplied to the various phone manufacturers.

However, the reason your camera can respond to ("see") IR remote controllers and the like is that the IR filters are not 100% blocking -- and the IR emitters in the remotes are not narrowband.  They emit across a chunk of the spectrum outside our normal vision range but within the region of partial transmission of the camera's filter.  In addition, the remote puts out a high power level of IR compared with the normal background level (e.g. solar, room lights), so a measurable amount of energy reaches the detector pixels themselves.  These are silicon-based, so they respond a little way past 1.1 micron wavelength.